# Convert column matrix to multiple rows with duplicated data

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, given matrix 'a' as:

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]';
```

but a few million rows deep, what would be the best way to convert it to the format shown in 'b'?

```
b = [1 2 3 4 5 6
     2 3 4 5 6 7
     3 4 5 6 7 8
     4 5 6 7 8 9]
```

where each row in 'b' contains N consecutive values from 'a'?

I can write a function but was wondering if there's a faster, more built-in way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is the built-in Hankel matrix, for example in your case:

```
hankel(1:4,4:9)
```

or in the general case for a vector `a` and block size `N`

```
hankel(a(1:N),a(N:numel(a)))
```

I have no idea if the implementation of hankel is better or worse than @Luis Mendo solution, so test and see which solution is better for you...

Answer (score 1):

Let

```
a = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9].'; % data
N = 4; % block size
```

- If you have the Image Processing Toolbox: use [`im2col`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2col.html) with the `'sliding'` option:

  ```
  b = im2col(a(:), [N 1], 'sliding');
  ```
- Or, without any toolbox: use [implict expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (or [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)) to create the appropriate indexing matrix:

  ```
  b = a((1:numel(a)-N+1)+(0:N-1).');
  ```